# How to show recenter button only when map moves using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm using the default Google Map recenter button which is shown by default. How do I ensure that the recenter button is not shown by default and it's only shown when someone moves the map using Swift?

```
func SetupMap() {
    googleMapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy. You know how to toggle the visibility of the `myLocationButton`, so what's left is to think harder.

If you take time to review the GoogleMap's `GMSMapViewDelegate`, you will see that there are couple of methods/functions that will allow you to further your idea.

So set your mapView's delegate to your class (controller), and conform to that `GMSMapViewDelegate` protocol, and then implement those methods.

1. willMove
2. didChange position

These are all you need.

The `willMove` gets invoked when you start dragging the mapView. On the other hand, the `didChange position` gets called when the camera did change.

If you do these things, you'll get even nearer towards your goal. However, you might need some `debounce` feature in your code, because you only want to hide the location button just once, just after the user stops dragging the camera.

```
var debounce_timer: Timer?

extension MapsViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
        print("GMS: will move")
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        print("GMS: didChane camera position")
        debounce_timer?.invalidate()
        debounce_timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { _ in
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = false
        }
    }
}
```

Voila!

---

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Few issues I have faced using this technique. By default, it's hidden as required but when the user drags the map it appears for a few seconds and then hides again. What I essentially want it when the user drags it should be visible until the user tap on the button which will do two things. 1. reposition user to it's location 2. the button will disappear.